# Using commands concerning DBGrid from the main form in another form

Tags: delphi, dbgrid, tform

I'm making a simple program for use in automotive parts shop. Here's how it's supposed to look: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYrvL.png)

The problem is the small window on the left. It should be opened when double clicked on any of the rows in DBGrid in the main window, and it should show all of the selected item's characteristics in DBEdit fields. If the Save button is clicked it should save the changes from the DBEdit fields into the database, but otherwise it should just ignore the changes.

I succeeded opening another form by double click on a field in DBGrid by using this code:

```
    procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    if not Assigned(Form2)
            then Form2 := TForm2.Create(Application);
    Form2.Show;
    end;
```

The only problem now is how to get the program to detect which row in the DBGrid is selected and then show its contents in DBEdit fields in the smaller window.

Can anyone tell me how to do this, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `TDBEdits` to `TForm2`, and connect them to the same `DataSource` as the `DBGrid` is using. They will automatically show the contents of the same row that is selected in the `DBGrid`, and you can edit or insert into the `DataSource's` `DataSet` and have the new or changed data appear in the `DBGrid` automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I tried doing that, but when I add a TDBEdit to TForm2, and try to assign the same DataSource to it as I did to TDBgrid, it doesn't appear in the list of data sources. 

I'm using Delphi 6, so could that be a problem?

Comment: You have to add the unit containing the DataSource to the uses clause of TForm2 (the interface, or top, uses clause). It works fine in Delphi all the way back to version 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. I'll describe two:

- If you link the DBEdits in the little window to the same DataSource as the DBGrid's, then you are all set

OR

- You can pass whatever info you want inside `DBGrid1DblClick` from Form1 to Form2. This option, by itself, has many possibilities.

**Update**

For the DataSource to be visible in Form2, unit to make Form2's unit use Form1's unit.